# Forwarding live Calls to a new Twiml from the browser

Tags: twilio

I am following the tutorial on https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state#post I am coding in php the portion that allows you to forward a current inbound call to a new Twiml URL. How do I get the inbound call Sid? Currently, the call Sid that I am retrieving forwards my browser to the new Twiml URL and hangs up the inbound caller. I think that I may have the wrong call Sid since I want to forward the current inbound caller to the new Twiml URL. Not The Browser. Can someone please give me some advice on retrieving the inbound call Sid to use in this php script? Thanks

```
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
        callSid = conn.parameters.CallSid; 
        $("#log").text("Incoming connection from " + conn.parameters.From);
        // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
        conn.accept();
      });
```

This is how I am getting the Call Sid. If I input this Call Sid into

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('TwilioAPI/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = '';
$token  = '';

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Get an object from its sid. If you do not have a sid,
// check out the list resource examples on this page
$call = $client->account->calls->get("THE CALL SID I GOT FROM THE JS GOES HERE");
$call->update(array(
        "Url" => "http://twimlets.com/message?Message%5B0%5D=I%20finally%20did%20it&",
    "Method" => "POST"
    ));
echo $call->to;
?>
```

This code forwards the browser which receives the call to the new Twiml URL. Not the inbound caller.

Comment: I've answered this issue on your previous question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809261/redirecting-a-call-to-a-new-twiml-url/30843854#30843854